# how to use <hr> in mid line in html?

Tags: html, css

I have seen lots of tutorials but not found solution anywhere. I am using hr tag in `html` to show lines on top and bottom, its working proper. But when i try to use hr tag to show line in center, its not working. I want to show line in center and also want to show some text there. As i am new if some help me with some code its easy to learn.

I want to show something like this-

```
------------------------Hello--------------------------
```

But i want the line above in solid form.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sriraman/5pMDK/53/)

HTML

```
<div>
   <div><hr></div>
   <span> Hello  </span>
   <div><hr></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  width:300px;
  text-align:center;
  display:table;
}
div > div {
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
div > span {
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: - 1 you have line on only one side

Comment: Sorry. Now, I fixed the problem. Now try the updated fiddle.

Comment: +1 :) for fixing the mistake

Comment: Thanks for showing me the mistake. The previous demo working correctly in chrome. But, not working in firefox. Thats why I can't notice the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theStudent/56Q2F/2/

```
<div style="height: 1px; background-color: black; text-align: center">
  <span style="background-color: white; position: relative; top: -0.55em; padding: 5px;">
    HELLO WORLD
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/9Y2Z4/

```
<div>sometext</div>
<div class="line">test here</div>
<div>again some text</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.line {
     height: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;

    border-bottom: 2px solid Red;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.line:first-line {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach as well, +1 mine is just very straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
  <div class="divline"> <span class="spans">
        HELLO WORLD
      </span>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divline {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
.spans {
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.55em;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tsz8n/3/)

[Check this too](http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/wcDbB)

Answer (score 0):

Each `<hr>` element returns rule to the beginning of the line (carriage return). You can try this:

```
.line{
    width:100px;
    height:1px;
    background:#ff0000;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.text{
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="text">Hello</div>
<div class="line"></div>
```